# evalute expression output into variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to be able to build a `Get-ADComputer` command after building it from strings like so:

`$FilterOperatingSystems = "*Windows 7*" -or OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 8*"  -or OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 10*"`

(`$FilterOperatingSystems` is a parameter to the script, so it'll be future proofed when executed by a Task Scheduler)

```
$command='Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like '+$FilterOperatingSystems+' )} |'
$command+= 'Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} | '
$command+= 'Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} | '
$command+= 'Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} | '
$command+= 'Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} | '
$command+= 'Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} | '
$command+= 'Where-Object {$|_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} | '
$command+= 'Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} | '
$command+= 'Select-Object -Expand Name'

Write-Host $command

$computer =iex $command
```

the `$command` comes out like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 7*" -or OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 8*"  -or OperatingSystem
 -like "*Windows 10*"  )} |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} | W
here-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} | Where-Object {$|_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} | Where-Obje
ct {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

but I get an error:

> $ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

So, is it possible to do something like that? And if so, what's the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a typo:

```
$|_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"
```

Should that not be `$_.name`?

Comment: DOH! - Thanks... my eye's failed me